# How to Parse Unix Log Time in Go

Tags: datetime, go, timezone, timezone-offset

I'm trying to parse the time portion of a *nix log line which is in EST time zone, and get the value in UTC.  e.g.

```
dts   := "Dec 11 15:03:58 EST"
dt, _ := time.Parse("Jan 2 15:04:05 MST", dts)
fmt.Printf("EST: %s \t UTC: %s\n", dt, dt.In(time.UTC))
```

But both values  are the same:

> EST: 0000-12-11 15:03:58 +0000 EST
>   UTC: 0000-12-11 15:03:58 +0000 UTC

I expected the UTC time to be 20:03:58

What am I doing wrong?

Go Playground at https://play.golang.org/p/54PsZ6y8R9_Y

Comment: "When parsing a time with a zone abbreviation like MST, if the zone abbreviation has a defined offset in the current location, then that offset is used. [...] If the zone abbreviation is unknown, Parse records the time as being in a fabricated location with the given zone abbreviation and a zero offset." https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse Abbreviations are generally ambiguous. Use ParseInLocation instead of Parse.

Comment: @Peter, please post it as an answer and I will accept it.